# jQuery Show() open at same time

Tags: jquery

Hello I am making a simple show function and if a user clicks any where else on the page the show turns into a hide. That worked until i added another show and hide function. I want it so when a user triggers to show a div the div that is open closes and then the div they want to open opens. Right now they both open. Here is the code: Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hBb9L/19/

```
 $("#e").click(function (e) {

    $("#s").show(200);
    e.stopPropagation();


    $("body").click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('popu')) {


            $("#s").hide(200);

        }
    });
});

 $("#er").click(function (er) {

    $("#u").show(200);
    er.stopPropagation();


    $("body").click(function (er) {
        if (!$(er.target).hasClass('popu')) {


            $("#u").hide(200);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Or show us some HTML?

Comment: I would look into [this](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/bootstrap-popover). Scroll to the part with the big, red "click me!" button. They explain how to do something very similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delay() it will made it work!